# sudo/su command for Red Hat Server 5.4

Tags: linux, command-line, redhat-enterprise-linux

Without going into too much detail, I need to execute one linux command on redhat with root user access. Red Hat Server 5.4 does not recognise the sudo command.

The command su can be used to switch to the root user on redhat, but su cannot be done in one line. For example the command:

```
su ; cd opt/storage/RootAccessFolder
```

will not work because this only switches you to root, then executes the cd command once you have logged out from the root user.

I guess what i'm looking for is like a..

```
sudo cd opt/storage/RootAccessFolder
```

but I say again, sudo doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Move this question to Unix & Linux http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can install `sudo` command or use the command below.

`su -l root -c 'cd opt/storage/RootAccessFolder'`